# Menu pushes rest of page down when

Tags: html, css

How can I make my menu not affect code below it?  I think `position:fixed;` will fix this problem but I am unsure.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chaddly/u9EEt/#base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to add `.menu { position:absolute; top: 45px; }`.

The `position:absolute` property will take the submenu out of the layout flow which will allow it to appear above the following text. The submenu will then not require any 'space' on the page. The `top:45px` will position the submenu correctly.

You will also need to set the submenu's parent element to `position:relative` to ensure that  the submenu element is positioned relative to it's parent element. In this case, this will be `45px` from the top!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9EEt/8/

Comment: Note that you should also position your `.menuaccess` div relative so the top argument is compared to this containing div and not to the document

Comment: Thank you for the help but even more for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use absolute position for your menu:

```
position:absolute;
top:55px;
right:8px;
z-index:9999;
```

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9EEt/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I used `position:absolute`.
Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/u9EEt/4/

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding display: fixed

```
.menu {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9EEt/2/

Comment: This will make the menu be over your content, even if you scroll down while still hovering over it